Unexpected Application Error! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')
I've been following this tutorial by Lama Dev, and I encountered the error message Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes') by writing the exact code (source code here) as Lama Dev's:
{data.includes(currentUser.id) ? (
  <FavoriteOutlinedIcon style={{color: "red"}} />
) : (
  <FavoriteBorderOutlinedIcon />
)}

I wonder what is the problem here.

The data variable will be undefined while you're still fetching.
So first, before you do data.includes, you have to check if data is not undefined. Equivalently, in this specific example, you can (following the tutorial you provided) check if the value of isLoading is false then you know you have data and you can do data.includes.
In short:
{data && data.includes(currentUser.id) ? (
  <FavoriteOutlinedIcon style={{color: "red"}} />
) : (
  <FavoriteBorderOutlinedIcon />
)}


Has this to do with the tutorial being made in an earlier version of React?

no, it seems like you miscopied the code from the tutorial :)
